# I can't make button add a class to newly created <li> element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple to-do list. I've managed to create the button but, I can't make it delete the item when click. In the console it says:

> li is not defined

```js
let getText = document.querySelector(".text");
let getUl = document.querySelector(".list");
let dBtn = document.createElement("button");

function addItem() {
  let newLi = document.createElement("li");
  newLi.innerHTML = getText.value;
  newLi.appendChild(dBtn);
  getUl.appendChild(newLi);
  getText.value = "";
}

dBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X"));

dBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  li.classList.add("delete");
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-add {
  height: 19px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.delete {
  display: none;
}

.text {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>to-do list</h1>
<input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Item to add ...">
<button type="button" class="button-add" onclick="addItem()">Add</button><br>
<ul class="list">

</ul>
```

Comment: Where have you defined "li" in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the class `delete` to `li` will not delete the item when you click.

The current code is adding the button only to the first `li` created. I believe you want to add button with each `li`. If so, you have to add the button functionality when you create the `li`.

Replace the click handler function code with:

```
this.parentNode.remove();
```

This will remove the current `li`.

```js
let getText = document.querySelector(".text");
let getUl = document.querySelector(".list");

function addItem (){
  let newLi = document.createElement("li");
  let dBtn = document.createElement("button");
  dBtn.addEventListener("click", removeLi);
  newLi.innerHTML=getText.value;
  dBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X"));
  newLi.appendChild(dBtn);
  getUl.appendChild(newLi);
  getText.value="";
}

function removeLi()  {
  this.parentNode.remove();
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-add {
  height: 19px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.delete{
  display: none;
}

.text {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>to-do list</h1>
    <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Item to add ...">
    <button type="button" class="button-add" onclick="addItem()">Add</button><br>
    <ul class="list">

    </ul>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: still doesnt want to remove the newly created list

Comment: @Frozendawn, where it is not working? In this answer or in your actual code??

Comment: thanks a lot , it made it just as i wanted it to be I was only trying to edit the last part and I was wondering why was it not working

Comment: @Frozendawn, you are most welcome. The issue was, `li` was not referencing the the element as you didn't define it, like you did with other variables. Then since the button is inside the `li`, you need to create button and attach the click event as part of each `li`. For that reason you should place that functionality inside `addItem()`............thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because addItem() is not defined. You are declaring it after the element.

try to remove onclick="" from the button e give it the onclick in js

replace `function addItem(){ .. }` like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('button-add')[0].onclick = function (){
  let newLi = document.createElement("li");
  newLi.innerHTML=getText.value;
  newLi.appendChild(dBtn);
  getUl.appendChild(newLi);
  getText.value="";
}
```

for delete

```
dBtn.addEventListener("click",function ()  {
  this.parentNode.classList.add("delete");
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dj1eya95/3/

Comment: Obviously, now the "X" is always on the last li. If you need to solve this we can do it :)

Comment: thanks this worked i just have to figure out how to put the x next to every new li

Comment: Put the logic in onclick function


`let getText = document.querySelector(".text");
let getUl = document.querySelector(".list");

document.getElementsByClassName('button-add')[0].onclick = function (){
  let newLi = document.createElement("li");
  let dBtn = document.createElement("button");
  newLi.innerHTML=getText.value;
  newLi.appendChild(dBtn);
  getUl.appendChild(newLi);
  getText.value="";
  dBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X"));

  dBtn.addEventListener("click",function ()  {
    this.parentNode.classList.add("delete");
  })
}`